# How to include a 'Many to Many' or 'Many to One' field in Django's generic CreateView?

Tags: django, many-to-many, create-view

I Have these two models:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza_type = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Toppings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    pizza_types = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to set the topping for a pizza in the pizza create view yet I don't know what field to pass to it, Or even f it should be a field.

```
class CreatePizza(CreateView):
    model = Pizza
    fields = ['pizza_type', '?How to reference a topping here?' ]
```

Would be glad if someone would help me out.
I assume the process is the same for Many to One field, but if not, I'll like to know how to accomplish this with them too.
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if its going to work, but try with: `fields = ['pizza_type', 'toppings_set']`.

Comment: Sadly no dice. "Unknown field(s) (toppings_set) specified for Pizza"

Comment: I don get it, do you wanna save a non existing field inside pizza model ?, or just show a pizza type list to save it in topping model at the same time as the pizza recording ?

Comment: @jsanchez When I create a Pizza I want to specify what Toppings it has.Let's say there are two existing toppings Olives and Mushrooms. When I create a Pizza I want to have a field to specify what toppings I want on the pizza.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **created** the *ManyToManyField* field in **Toppings** model, then while **creating** an object of **Pizza** model, you **can't** have a field which says what type of toppings that pizza can have as when Django reads the **Pizza** model from your models.py, it doesn't gets any such field.

In short, you can only tell the object of that model which has the ManyToManyField that what all objects of other model 'X' it is associated to. That too you can't associate them without first creating and saving them first.

**In your case**, you need to create a pizza of model "Pizza" say Farmhouse.
Then you need to create objects of model "Toppings" say Olives and Mushrooms, if they already don't exist.
And then after saving the above objects, you need to add Farmhouse to Olives and to Mushrooms.

So now when you query for the toppings of Farmhouse pizza, you'll get a list containing

```
[<Toppings: Olives> <Toppings: Mushrooms>]
```

You can do it the other way round also by setting the *ManyToManyField* in **Pizza** model and hence create object of Pizza Model say Farmhouse again and then adding the toppings Olives and Mushrooms to it.

See this for better understanding: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/